# Copying values into an Excel Table using VBA without having the extra rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to copy values from one worksheet, and then pasting it into an existing Excel table.  However, I can't figure out why the table has extra rows.  For instance, the source workbook may have about 1500 rows, but the resulting destination table ends up with about 20000 additional rows.

Below is a snippet of the copying and pasting.

```
    Dim sourceWkb2 As Workbook
    Dim sourceWks2 As Worksheet
    Dim targetWks2 As Worksheet
    Dim sourceFilename2 As String
    Dim GetFileName2(1 To 3) As String
    Dim j As Integer
    
    Dim lLastRow1 As Long

    Set targetWks2 = Sheets("RTH test")
    sourceFilename2 = GetFileName2(1)
    Set sourceWkb2 = Workbooks.Open(sourceFilename2)
    Set sourceWks2 = sourceWkb2.Sheets(1)

    lLastRow1 = sourceWks2.Cells(sourceWks2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Clear the current RTH table
    With targetWks2.ListObjects("RTH_testtable")
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.Delete
            .Resize .Range.Resize(lLastRow1, .ListColumns.Count)
        End If
    End With
    
    'Paste the source data into the newly cleared RTH table
    sourceWks2.Range("A2:G2" & lLastRow1).Copy _
    targetWks2.Range("A2:G2" & lLastRow1)
    
    MsgBox lLastRow1
```

Comment: `targetWks2.Range("A2:G" & lLastRow1)` (second to last line) - remove the extra `2`. Same for `sourceWks2.Range("A2:G" & lLastRow1)`.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked.